# rename all subdirectories of directory in php

Tags: php

I have a directory structure like so:

```
.
├── uploads
|   ├── 1
|   |   ├── example.jpeg
|   |   └── example.jpeg
|   ├── 2
|   |   └── example.jpeg
|   ├── 3
|   |   ├── example.jpeg
|   |   ├── example.jpeg
|   |   └── example.jpeg
```

I wish to rename all the directories in my firectory `uploads` (in my example these are called `1`, `2` and `3`). I want to rename all of these directories based on their current name. For example, I want `1` to become `1asd`, `2` to `2asd` and `3` to `3asd`. I have looked for similar questions and found [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128852/loop-and-rename-all-subfolders-in-php) (which although the question seems similar is actually about something else) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955323/using-php-to-rename-all-files-in-folder), which is about renaming files. 
I tried:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../path/to/uploads')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = $fileName.'asd';
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

This doesn't work because all `$filename` is always `.`. My guess is because it's about directories and not files. How do I target the directories instead?

**side-note1**: the directories I wish to rename contain files which I do not want to lose/delete. In my example they are all called `example.jpeg`.

**side-note2**: the path to my `uploads` directory is correct, I tested this.

Comment: There is a syntax error in `$newName = $fileName.'asd');`, note the closing parentheses? Is it just a typo?

Comment: @mcserep, thx. Not what it is though, this was just a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [`rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).

Make sure that you run this from the proper directory or change the path accordingly.

Works as it is if your `PHP` script is located on the parent directory of `uploads`

```
foreach (glob("uploads/[1|2|3]",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
    rename($filename, $filename."asd");
}
```

In case of multiple directories the above would change a bit to the following:

```
$directories = array_merge_recursive(glob("uploads/[0-9]*[0-9]",GLOB_ONLYDIR),glob("uploads/[0-9]",GLOB_ONLYDIR));

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    rename($directory, $directory."asd");
}
```

`glob("uploads/[0-9]*[0-9]",GLOB_ONLYDIR)` matches anything starting from a number and ending to one.

`glob("uploads/[0-9]",GLOB_ONLYDIR)` matches any directory that has a single digit number for name.

Comment: How would I do this when I have hundreds of sub-directories with different numbers?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Do the sub-directory numbers have a pattern? You can perform a regular expression as in the example above.

Comment: All of the sub-directories consist of numbers. Anywhere between 1 and 99999, but it's not 1,2,3 etc...

Answer (score 0):

You want to check to make sure it is a directory and check that it is not the current directory `.` or the parent `..` directory:

```
if(is_dir($fileName) && $fileName!= "." && $fileName!= "..") {
   $newName = $fileName.'asd';
   rename($fileName, $newName);
}
```

Also, as [mcserep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005299/mcserep) states *There is a syntax error in `$newName = $fileName.'asd');`, note the closing parentheses.*

Comment: somehow this does not work. I tried to `var_dump` and get nothing. When I `var_dump` with `is_dir($filename` I do get to see my directories. But then when I run the code I get an error like: `Warning: rename(135,135asd): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)`

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I managed to figure out a solution:

```
$dir = '../path/to/uploads/';

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($filename = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if($filename!= "." && $filename!= "..") {
                        rename($dir.$filename, $dir.$filename."asd");
                    }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```